# Adding a new system call in Linux kernel 3.3

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am very new to this kernel thing. What I want to do is just add a new system call to the kernel. I was following this guideline: http://hekimian-williams.com/?p=20.

The problem is there used to syscall_table_32.S file under arch/x86/kernel, but I cannot find the file for x86 systems in kernel version 3.3. Do I still need to edit the file and append one more line for the newly added system call? Or do I need to do something else to let the kernel know about my new system call? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in kernel 3.3 its shifted here

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/syscalls/

Comment: Sometime I wonder if there is anything you guys do not know.. ^^

Answer (score 7):

How to add a new Linux kernel API in 3.3 version?
-- for 64 bits OS

- get kernel codes from www.kernel.org.

wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.3.1.tar.bz2

- Upzip it with command ‘tar xvfj XXX” to a folder
  For example : /root/kernel
  tar xvfj linux-3.3.1.tar.bz2
- Edit file “/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl”
  Add new line

312     64      husky1                  sys_husky1

- Eidt file “/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/include/linux/syscalls.h”
  Add new function declaration

asmlinkage long sys_husky1(int fd);

before the line “#endif”

- Add a new c file under “/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/arch/x86/kernel” (I am using x86 CPU)
  Example :
- Edit “/root/kernel/linux-3.3.1/arch/x86/kernel/Makefile”
  Add a new line 
  “obj-y  += husky.o”
- goto /root/kernel/linux-3.3.1 folder and run command “make –j8”